# Dojo Mobile - Carousel Slideshow using 1.7+ preferred api's?

Tags: javascript, mobile, carousel, dojo

Using Dojo Mobile 1.7.2, I'm having trouble getting a simple carousel slideshow to work. I've been at this single problem for the best part of a day now

Basically, I'm trying to recreate this example: -

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.2/dojo-release-1.7.2/dojox/mobile/tests/test_Carousel-slideshow.html

but using the 1.7+ preferred api (from http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/mobile.html): -

```
require([
  "dojox/mobile/parser", // (Optional) This mobile app uses declarative programming with fast mobile parser
  "dojox/mobile",        // (Required) This is a mobile app.
  "dojox/mobile/compat"  // (Optional) This mobile app supports running on desktop browsers
], function(parser, mobile, compat){ Optional module aliases that can then be referenced inside callback block
  // Do something with mobile api's.  At this point Dojo Mobile api's are ready for use.
);
```

I've managed everything else using this method so don't want to have to revert to the pre-1.7 style api's as that is just going backwards...but unfortunately most of the demos (even for 1.7.2) still use the old style api.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is broken in dojo 1.7. 1.8 fixes the issue.